# How to store data attribute values in localstorage with same class

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have four options i.e, Body, Sleeves, Collar and Cuffs and each option is having multiple colors. I have class called "custom-colors" for all the checkboxes. When I click on checkbox of body type I want to get data-image attribute of body type and whichever is checked am adding class for that checkbox called "checked" and also I want store this values in localstorage using checked class and same for other options. For example I want data like below,
{'body-image':'1.png','sleeves-image':'1.png','collar-image':'1.png','cuffs-image':1.png''}. But I want to store separately for body, sleeves, collar and cuffs with the same class i.e, Generic wise. How to acheive this please some one help me.

Below is Html,

```
<label class="control-label">Body</label>
    <div class="radio">
      <span class="set-color" data-color="white">
        <label for="option-value-762" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="1" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/White-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="762" id="option-value-762" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/White-50x50.png" alt="White" /> -->
        White                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="red">
        <label for="option-value-755" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="2" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/1935U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="755" id="option-value-755" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/1935U-50x50.png" alt="Red" /> -->
        Red                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="green">
        <label for="option-value-764" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="3" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/354U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="764" id="option-value-764" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/354U-50x50.png" alt="Green" /> -->
        Green                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="blue">
        <label for="option-value-754" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="4" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/286U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="754" id="option-value-754" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/286U-50x50.png" alt="Blue" /> -->
        Blue                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="black">
        <label for="option-value-765" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="5" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/BlackU-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="765" id="option-value-765" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/BlackU-50x50.png" alt="Black" /> -->
        Black                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="grey">
        <label for="option-value-761" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="6" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/421U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="761" id="option-value-761" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/421U-50x50.png" alt="Grey" /> -->
        Grey                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="yellow">
        <label for="option-value-763" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="7" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/128U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="763" id="option-value-763" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/128U-50x50.png" alt="Yellow" /> -->
        Yellow                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
    </div>




<label class="control-label">Sleeves</label>
    <div class="radio">
      <span class="set-color" data-color="white">
      <label for="option-value-771" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="1" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/White-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="771" id="option-value-771" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/White-50x50.png" alt="White" /> -->
      White                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="red">
      <label for="option-value-770" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="2" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/1935U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="770" id="option-value-770" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/1935U-50x50.png" alt="Red" /> -->
      Red                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="green">
      <label for="option-value-768" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="3" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/354U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="768" id="option-value-768" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/354U-50x50.png" alt="Green" /> -->
      Green                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="blue">
      <label for="option-value-767" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="4" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/286U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="767" id="option-value-767" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/286U-50x50.png" alt="Blue" /> -->
      Blue                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="black">
      <label for="option-value-766" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="5" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/BlackU-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="766" id="option-value-766" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/BlackU-50x50.png" alt="Black" /> -->
      Black                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="grey">
      <label for="option-value-769" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="6" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/Black0961-U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="769" id="option-value-769" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/Black0961-U-50x50.png" alt="Grey" /> -->
      Grey                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="yellow">
      <label for="option-value-772" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="7" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/128U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="772" id="option-value-772" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/128U-50x50.png" alt="Yellow" /> -->
      Yellow                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
    </div>

<label class="control-label">Collar</label>
    <div class="radio">
      <span class="set-color" data-color="white">
        <label for="option-value-803" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="1" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/White-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="803" id="option-value-803" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/White-50x50.png" alt="White" /> -->
        White                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="red">
        <label for="option-value-804" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="2" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/1935U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="804" id="option-value-804" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/1935U-50x50.png" alt="Red" /> -->
        Red                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="green">
        <label for="option-value-805" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="3" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/354U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="805" id="option-value-805" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/354U-50x50.png" alt="Green" /> -->
        Green                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="blue">
        <label for="option-value-806" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="4" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/286U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="806" id="option-value-806" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/286U-50x50.png" alt="Blue" /> -->
        Blue                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="black">
        <label for="option-value-807" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="5" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/BlackU-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="807" id="option-value-807" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/BlackU-50x50.png" alt="Black" /> -->
        Black                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="grey">
        <label for="option-value-808" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="6" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/421U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="808" id="option-value-808" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/421U-50x50.png" alt="Grey" /> -->
        Grey                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
      <span class="set-color" data-color="yellow">
        <label for="option-value-809" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="7" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/128U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="809" id="option-value-809" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/128U-50x50.png" alt="Yellow" /> -->
        Yellow                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
    </div>




<label class="control-label">Cuffs</label>
    <div class="radio">
      <span class="set-color" data-color="white">
        <label for="option-value-778" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="1" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/White-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="778" id="option-value-778" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/White-50x50.png" alt="White" /> -->
        White                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
        <span class="set-color" data-color="red">
        <label for="option-value-777" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="2" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/1935U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="777" id="option-value-777" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/1935U-50x50.png" alt="Red" /> -->
        Red                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
        <span class="set-color" data-color="green">
        <label for="option-value-775" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="3" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/354U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="775" id="option-value-775" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/354U-50x50.png" alt="Green" /> -->
        Green                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
        <span class="set-color" data-color="blue">
        <label for="option-value-774" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="4" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/286U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="774" id="option-value-774" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/286U-50x50.png" alt="Blue" /> -->
        Blue                                                </div>
      </label>
      </span>
        <span class="set-color" data-color="black">
        <label for="option-value-773" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="5" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/BlackU-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="773"         Yellow                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
    </div>id="option-value-773" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/BlackU-50x50.png" alt="Black" /> -->
        Black                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
        <span class="set-color" data-color="grey">
        <label for="option-value-776" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="6" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/7757U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="776" id="option-value-776" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/7757U-50x50.png" alt="Grey" /> -->
        Grey                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
        <span class="set-color" data-color="yellow">
        <label for="option-value-779" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="7" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/128U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="779" id="option-value-779" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/128U-50x50.png" alt="Yellow" /> -->
        Yellow                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Below is my jquery,

```
$('.custom-colors').change(function() {
  var image_index = $(this).data("index");
  alert(image_index);
  if(image_index)
  {
    $(this).addClass("checked");
  }
  $(this).each(function(){
      var class_active = $(this).hasClass('checked');
      if(class_active == true){
        var image_src = $(this).data("image");
        localStorage.setItem('body-image',image_src);
      }
      else
      {
        localStorage.removeItem('body-image');
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit unclear of you want multiple values from your checkboxes or just one for each "category". But here is an example I  made that might guide you in the right direction.

```
$('.custom-colors').change(function() {
  var image_index = $(this).data("index");
  //alert(image_index);
  if (image_index) {
    $(this).addClass("checked");
  }

  r()
});
var data = {};

function r() {
  $(".control-label").each(function() {
    var n = $(this).text();
    if ($(this).next().find(".checked").length > 0) {
      data[n] = {}
      var t = $.map($(this).next().find(".checked"), function(i, x) {
        return $(i).data("image")
      })
      data[n].data = t
      //localStorage.setItem(n, t) cant set here because of sandboxed.
    }
  });
  console.clear()
  console.log(data)

}
```

```js
$('.custom-colors').change(function() {
  var image_index = $(this).data("index");
  //alert(image_index);
  if (image_index) {
    $(this).addClass("checked");
  }

  r()
});
var data = {};

function r() {
  $(".control-label").each(function() {
    var n = $(this).text();
    if ($(this).next().find(".checked").length > 0) {
      data[n] = {}
      var t = $.map($(this).next().find(".checked"), function(i, x) {
        return $(i).data("image")
      })
      data[n].data = t
      //localStorage.setItem(n, t) cant set here because of sandboxed.
    }
  });
  console.clear()
  console.log(data)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="control-label">Body</label>
<div class="radio">
  <span class="set-color" data-color="white">
        <label for="option-value-762" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="1" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/White-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="762" id="option-value-762" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/White-50x50.png" alt="White" /> -->
        White                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="red">
        <label for="option-value-755" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="2" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/1935U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="755" id="option-value-755" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/1935U-50x50.png" alt="Red" /> -->
        Red                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="green">
        <label for="option-value-764" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="3" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/354U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="764" id="option-value-764" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/354U-50x50.png" alt="Green" /> -->
        Green                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="blue">
        <label for="option-value-754" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="4" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/286U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="754" id="option-value-754" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/286U-50x50.png" alt="Blue" /> -->
        Blue                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="black">
        <label for="option-value-765" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="5" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/BlackU-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="765" id="option-value-765" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/BlackU-50x50.png" alt="Black" /> -->
        Black                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="grey">
        <label for="option-value-761" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="6" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/421U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="761" id="option-value-761" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/421U-50x50.png" alt="Grey" /> -->
        Grey                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="yellow">
        <label for="option-value-763" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option152">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="7" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/128U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[152]" value="763" id="option-value-763" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/body/128U-50x50.png" alt="Yellow" /> -->
        Yellow                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
</div>




<label class="control-label">Sleeves</label>
<div class="radio">
  <span class="set-color" data-color="white">
      <label for="option-value-771" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="1" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/White-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="771" id="option-value-771" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/White-50x50.png" alt="White" /> -->
      White                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="red">
      <label for="option-value-770" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="2" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/1935U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="770" id="option-value-770" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/1935U-50x50.png" alt="Red" /> -->
      Red                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="green">
      <label for="option-value-768" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="3" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/354U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="768" id="option-value-768" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/354U-50x50.png" alt="Green" /> -->
      Green                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="blue">
      <label for="option-value-767" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="4" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/286U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="767" id="option-value-767" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/286U-50x50.png" alt="Blue" /> -->
      Blue                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="black">
      <label for="option-value-766" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="5" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/BlackU-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="766" id="option-value-766" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/BlackU-50x50.png" alt="Black" /> -->
      Black                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="grey">
      <label for="option-value-769" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="6" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/Black0961-U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="769" id="option-value-769" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/Black0961-U-50x50.png" alt="Grey" /> -->
      Grey                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="yellow">
      <label for="option-value-772" style="color:transparent;">
      <div id="input-option154">
      <input type="checkbox" data-index="7" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/128U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[154]" value="772" id="option-value-772" />
      <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/sleeves/128U-50x50.png" alt="Yellow" /> -->
      Yellow                                                </div>
    </label>
    </span>
</div>

<label class="control-label">Collar</label>
<div class="radio">
  <span class="set-color" data-color="white">
        <label for="option-value-803" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="1" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/White-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="803" id="option-value-803" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/White-50x50.png" alt="White" /> -->
        White                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="red">
        <label for="option-value-804" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="2" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/1935U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="804" id="option-value-804" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/1935U-50x50.png" alt="Red" /> -->
        Red                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="green">
        <label for="option-value-805" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="3" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/354U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="805" id="option-value-805" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/354U-50x50.png" alt="Green" /> -->
        Green                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="blue">
        <label for="option-value-806" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="4" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/286U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="806" id="option-value-806" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/286U-50x50.png" alt="Blue" /> -->
        Blue                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="black">
        <label for="option-value-807" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="5" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/BlackU-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="807" id="option-value-807" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/BlackU-50x50.png" alt="Black" /> -->
        Black                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="grey">
        <label for="option-value-808" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="6" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/421U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="808" id="option-value-808" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/421U-50x50.png" alt="Grey" /> -->
        Grey                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="yellow">
        <label for="option-value-809" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option167">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="7" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/128U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[167]" value="809" id="option-value-809" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/collar/128U-50x50.png" alt="Yellow" /> -->
        Yellow                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
</div>




<label class="control-label">Cuffs</label>
<div class="radio">
  <span class="set-color" data-color="white">
        <label for="option-value-778" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="1" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/White-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="778" id="option-value-778" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/White-50x50.png" alt="White" /> -->
        White                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="red">
        <label for="option-value-777" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="2" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/1935U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="777" id="option-value-777" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/1935U-50x50.png" alt="Red" /> -->
        Red                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="green">
        <label for="option-value-775" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="3" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/354U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="775" id="option-value-775" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/354U-50x50.png" alt="Green" /> -->
        Green                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="blue">
        <label for="option-value-774" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="4" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/286U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="774" id="option-value-774" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/286U-50x50.png" alt="Blue" /> -->
        Blue                                                </div>
      </label>
      </span>
  <span class="set-color" data-color="black">
        <label for="option-value-773" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="5" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/BlackU-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="773"         Yellow                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
</div>id="option-value-773" />
<!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/BlackU-50x50.png" alt="Black" /> -->
Black </div>
</label>
</span>
<span class="set-color" data-color="grey">
        <label for="option-value-776" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="6" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/7757U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="776" id="option-value-776" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/7757U-50x50.png" alt="Grey" /> -->
        Grey                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
<span class="set-color" data-color="yellow">
        <label for="option-value-779" style="color:transparent;">
        <div id="input-option155">
        <input type="checkbox" data-index="7" data-image="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/128U-50x50.png" class="custom-colors" name="option[155]" value="779" id="option-value-779" />
        <!-- <img src="http://192.168.1.156/dutees/image/cache/catalog/pngs/cuffs/128U-50x50.png" alt="Yellow" /> -->
        Yellow                                                </div>
        </label>
      </span>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working actually console.log(data) is showing empty

Comment: @Mohan Well i took you exact code you posted, so if you took mine it should work